# Create a Common Identifier Across Columns with the Same Data

Tags: t-sql, server

I have a dictionary containing the original word, and altforms of the word. What I have currently is something like this:

```
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         WordID      |         Word        |     OrigWord     |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         1           |          aah        |       null       |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         2           |         aahs        |        aah       |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         3           |         aahed       |        aah       |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         4           |        aahing       |        aah       |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

I have around 270,000 words in the dictionary with a similar layout to this.

Is there a fairly simple way to create an ID for each inflected form that links back to the original word similar to below?

```
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         WordID      |         LinkID      |         Word        |     OrigWord     |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         1           |         null        |          aah        |       null       |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         2           |         1           |         aahs        |        aah       |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         3           |         1           |         aahed       |        aah       |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         4           |         1           |        aahing       |        aah       |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         5           |         null        |      aardvark       |       null       |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|    
|         6           |         5           |      aardvarks      |     aardvark     |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

EDIT:

Added second example word to further explain LinkID functionality

Comment: Can you please explain your requirement bit more, why LinkID is 1 for all rows?

Comment: This is just a snippet of words from a dictionary. Each inflected word is linked to the original word. I've added another couple of rows to try and further explain the requirement. The Link ID will link back to the WordID of the original word, from one of the inflections or altwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by a self join:

```
SELECT t1.WordID, 
       t2.WordID as LinkID, 
       t1.Word,
       t1.OrigWord
FROM Words t1 LEFT JOIN Words t2 ON t1.OrigWord = t2.Word
```